# Has ping to MySQL Server, but fails to connect through C# code

Tags: c#, mysql, database, connection

I'm using a C# program to connect to a database and display data in a grid (TableFromMySql).

I installed my program on a PC that sits on the same network as the database. Ping is okay, but my program fails to connect, it reaches the catch statement and shows me "No connection to DB" error.

```
private void SQLMethod(string query)
{
        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (MySqlCommand cmdSel = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdSel);
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    TableFromMySql = dt.DefaultView;

                    if (TableFromMySql.Count == 0)
                        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("No results.", "INFO", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }        
        catch
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("No connection to " + serverIP, "ERROR", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
}
```

Connection string is a string value:

```
private const string connectionString =
        "SERVER=IP;" +
        "PORT=3306;" +
        "DATABASE=db;" +
        "UID=root;" +
        "PASSWORD=password;";
```

A few notes:

1. **IP** is the actual ip address of the DB, can't post it.
2. Connecting to the DB using HeidiSQL from that PC works fine.
3. I also checked the same code on my local PC with an Ubuntu VM running MySQL Server docker container and the code worked.
4. To create the installation file I used the Visual Studio Installer extension.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error/exception message?

Comment: It reaches the catch statement (No connection to server). Can't debug because I use the installation file on a standalone PC and I use it as a program.

Comment: Yes. It is. I checked it on my local PC with a VM (only changed the IP) and it worked just fine.

Comment: Your question says SQL Server, but you are using MySqlConnection - which is for MySql. If you are using SQL Server, would the SqlConnection be a better approach?

Comment: Could you give me more details? @TimWooldridge
As I said, on my local PC I had an ubuntu VM with a docker container running MySQL Server. Code worked fine!

Comment: The MySql functionality - MySqlConnection, MySqlCommand, etc. is tailored towards being used for MySql databases. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlConnection.htm


There is an equivalent for SQL Server, called SqlConnection, SqlCommand etc. that are tailored for SQL Server connection. 

Details of SqlCommand are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: Thanks @TimWooldridge, I'll check and update!

Comment: @TimWooldridge Update: It doesn't work...

Comment: The issue is somewhere else then. However, my point still stands that you are better off using SqlConnect, SqlCommand, etc. rather than their MySql counterparts - as  they are tailored towards the correct database.

Comment: Change `catch` to `catch (Exception ex)` and add the full exception details to your question: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Answer (score 1):

So after a long time I found the answer. I added to the connection string "SslMode=None" and the problem was solved.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same issue where `Connection.Ping()` is returning true, but then actually trying to run statements gets me `System.InvalidOperationException: Connection must be valid and open.` I might have to make a new question in a bit if I can't figure it out.